# Pagination for UICollection View horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

We have implemented a horizontal scroller with `UICollectionView` by customizing the collection flow layout dimensions.
We wanted to show left pagination indicator and right pagination indicator to tell that there are more cells to the left and/or right.

To accomplish this, we have written the below  piece of code in the method;

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but it is not working properly. The max no of cells that can be shown are 5 (i.e. page size is 5).

```
if(_people.count > 5 && indexPath.row > 4) {
    // SHOW THE LEFT INDICATOR
    NSLog(@"images at left");
}
NSLog(@" %ld %lu", indexPath.row, _people.count);
if(_people.count > 5 && indexPath.row < _people.count-1) {
    // SHOW THE RIGHT INDICATOR
    NSLog(@"images at right");
}
```

This solution is working properly when we scroll slowly, but not working when we scroll very fast.
Please suggest how we can accomplish this.

Comment: Define "not working". Do you just have these log statements at the moment or are you doing something else?

Comment: Are you sure the paging indicators are causing the scroll lag? Also are both of the indicators a part of each cell?